# Featured Image not changing

Tags: images, pages, customization

Here is what the situation with my featured image. When I try to change the featured on my site. It doesn't change at all.

Here is how I currently try to change the featured image on my page:

1. I click on the Add Media button
2. Select the featured image option
3. Select the image
4. Then I click on the update page.

For some reason, the image will not change. It is still the old featured image. Is there a reason why it is not changing on the front end. When I go to Facebook or other various social media site, it still shows the old image.

I'm using Wordpress 5.1.1 and the featured image bug is happening on the pages. Not the post. The theme that I'm using is Dejure

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Comment: Hello Kevin :) Can you please clarify **where** is the featured image not changing: the back-end (admin area) or in the front-end of your website? Also, can you confirm where this is happening: a **post**, **page**, or someplace else? P.S. You can [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/333511/edit) your question to add these details there instead of replying to this comment, that way the information will be more visible to readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry you're having trouble with the featured image. Some details that will help the community solve the question: What theme are you using?

Without knowing what theme you're using, one approach you might try is removing the featured image from the post/page, then click update. If the featured image is removed, you might then be able to choose another featured image.

Another option would be to stop using the Media pop up window and updated the featured image from the Featured Image meta box on the Edit Post screen.

**Edit to add the solution from the comments**

If you tried the above and it didn't work, the next thing to do is switch themes, then attempt to change the featured image. If that works, then the issue is with the theme, and you might need a new copy of the theme. If that doesn't work, try deactivating all your plugins and then attempting to change it. There may be a plugin conflict as well.

Comment: I'm using a custom built theme called Dejure.

Comment: If you tried the above and it didn't work, the next thing to do is switch themes, then attempt to change the featured image. If that works, then the issue is with the theme, and you might need a new copy of the theme.

If that doesn't work, try deactivating all your plugins and then attempting to change it. There may be a plugin conflict as well.

Comment: That was the case. Will have to find a way to fix the template.

Comment: Glad you found the fix! If you could upvote my answer and accept it I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the image is not changing on the **front-end**, then it could be a **cache** issue.

The solution to fix that would depend on if you are using any cache plugin and which one, but sometimes simply clearing the browser cache works.

However, from your mention above of Facebook and your other question here on OpenGraph, then in your specific situation it could be that Facebook is not picking up the new image in WordPress.

You can use the Facebook debug tool and copy the URL of the WordPress page to it to see if there are any errors with your Featured Image thumbnail.

And/or you could use an alternative method to give Facebook explicit orders on what image to use.

I don't personally use a WordPress/Facebook setup so I cannot supplement my answer with screenshots and sample code (sorry!), but if you feel this is indeed what you need to solve your issue then you'll be able to find a lot of tutorials online on [how to get Facebook to use the Featured Image of your WordPress page](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=how+to+get+Facebook+to+use+the+Featured+Image+of+your+WordPress+page), such as this one example [here](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/facebook-debugger/).

I hope you find this information helpful and that it solves your issue.

Answer (score -2):

1- remove the image from your library,

2- change the image name in your pc,

3- upload it again,

I don't know why this works, but i had the same problem and i do this every time,
it will definitely works, hope it helps you

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: i dont know why, but it works for me